# How to avoid recursive dependencies in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which maintains a list of items that are fetched over time. The component fetches an item on load, and can also fetch new items as a result of user interaction. Whenever an item is fetched it should be added to the list of items. The following code goes into an infinite recursion, because each time I add a new item to `items`, the effect is called again with the new `items` list, and another item is added.

```
export default function UnintentionallyRecursive () {
  const [item, setItem] = useState()
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const fetchItem = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve({ title: 'a new item' }))

  const updateItem = useCallback(async () => {
    const newItem = await fetchItem()
    setItem(newItem)
  }, [setItem])

  useEffect(() => {
    updateItem()
  }, [updateItem])

  // this is the part that causes the recursion
  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(items.concat([item]))
  }, [item, items, setItems])

  return null // really UI code which can also call updateItem
}
```

How can I achieve this using Hooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update a state using a function with its current state as argument. This way you don't need `items` as a dependency.

```
setItems((currentState) => currentState.concat(item));

// is the same as
setItems([items].concat(item));
```

Sidenote: You also don't need to add `setItems` to your dependency array, it's save to leave out.

Comment: beat me to it by 30 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

TIL about `functional updates` in `useState`

replacing the offending `useEffect` call with this fixed the issue

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(items => items.concat([item]))
  }, [item, setItems])
```